# Rails redirect issue - Hartl's Rails Tutorial 10.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I'm a complete noob working through Michael Hartl's (awesome) Rails tutorials, and have an issue with the friendly redirect in Ch.10.2.3.  The purpose is to try to store the location, redirect to the sign in page, then redirect back to the original intended destination when sign-in is complete.  My problem is that it simply renders the standard user profile page after signing in/creating a session, rather than redirecting.

I have this in the sessions_controller:

```
def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                           params[:session][:password])
  if user.nil?
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
    @title = "Sign in"
    render 'new'
  else
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or user
  end
end
```

And this in sessions_helper:

```
def authenticate
  deny_access unless signed_in?
end

def deny_access
  store_location
  redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
end    

def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  clear_return_to
end

private
  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

 def clear_return_to
   session[:return_to] = nil
 end
```

I'm sure I've yet again made a stupid, simple mistake but I can't find it.. help?

Comment: Did you try `session[:return_to] = request.request_uri` ? it's been a while, so i can't recall if request.fullpath will have something that you can `redirect_to`. it possibly does, but figured it would be something easy you can check.

Comment: I have, but from other comments I think request_uri was deprecated with Rails 3.0.

Comment: It's hard not having all the code, But one thing to check would be: make sure the method 'store_location' is actually getting called somewhere during the login process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried it but it hasn't helped.  'store_location' is being called but there's nothing there.

Comment: Please include the rest of your `session_helper` class. Specifically the `deny_access` method and other that are missing.

Comment: The session_helper class has quite a lot of authentication related methods that I've left out, but I've updated the code above with 'deny_access', 'authenticate', and 'clear_return_to' methods.

Answer (score 1):

The code is available here: https://github.com/railstutorial
Consider making a new git branch (or new project) for yourself that uses just this repository's code.  Then you will have a working local version for comparison when things go wrong.

Comment: Good suggestion Perry. Is there a way you can easily compare two bodies of code to track the error?

Comment: My first thought is to use the unix command diff, but I don't know if that qualifies as easy.

Comment: Easy but time consuming! And with mixed results. There was no discernible difference, so I went back to where I knew for sure my tests were working (Chapter 9), started a new branch and did it all over again.  And it seems to work. So, the good news is that it's working, the bad news is I honestly have no idea why.  On the upside, at least I've added a surprisingly versatile new command to my repertoire.

Comment: Sounds familiar.  It's almost too bad Hartl brands his tutorial as "for rails."  He's introduced me to TDD and version control in ways that seem (are) new and super useful to me.  I did finish all 12 chapters of his tutorial and am now 7 chapters in to "The Well Grounded Rubyist"  You may like this text too.  I bought the pdf and it seems like a very good next step for me.  If I could get something top notch on rspec 2.0 I think I'd almost be ready to get started :-)

Comment: Agreed.  Notwithstanding the few issues I had, Hartl is very good at introducing new concepts in an easy to understand manner and I'd like to see more from him.  I've worked through about half of The Rails 3 Way but it seems to assume more background knowledge so some of it goes over my head at the moment - I'll take a look at The Well Grounded Rubyist, thanks for the suggestion.